# What Common Name I should set when buying an SSL certificate to navigate over HTTPS with my application?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, facebook-iframe

While buying a SSL certificate I am being asked to set a common name used by facebook to comunicate with our domain. How should this be set? with the domain name?
Any help would be appreciated,
Best regards,
Luca S.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a specific domain name that you don't expect to change use that.
I.e. have the certificate issued to your domain name.
Otherwise you can use variations of the domain name as part of the Subject Alternative Name extensions of your certificate

Answer (score -1):

Certificates for your webserver *always use the domain name* as common name.

Comment: That's not true, when the certificate has Subject Alternative Name entries of DNS type, these must be used, and the Common Name becomes irrelevant. See [RFC 2818 Section 3.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818#section-3.1).